# Update Cyanogenmod to latest Snapshot

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I am running Cyanogenmod on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus.
by the beginning of March 2014, Cyanogenmod released V11 Snapshot M4.
As far as I know, I am still running Snapshot M3, which I freshly installed in February.

When will 11 M4 arrive on my phone? Will it be available over-the-air?

There was one small OTA update in late February, was that already M4?
If I take a look at System -> Setting -> About Phone, there are various version and build numbers, but there is no number showing any Snapshot number...

Thanks in advance,
Sascha.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Indeed, the correct answer is, that installer build is quite a bit behind the manual installation. But also thanks to your answer - it was helpful too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answer.
If looking into "About phone", "Build Date" is "Tue Feb 25 14:46:23 PST 2014" and Build Number "cm_maguro-userdebug 4.4.2 KOT49H InstallerXNPQ09P release-keys"

According to build date, I guess that's still M3, right?

Last weekend I tried to manually update, by downloading the ZIP file for Maguro from http://download.cyanogenmod.org, but that ended up in a corrupted phone:

- phone app was missing, I wasn't able to receive calls
- home button didn't work (flashed when pressed, but nothing happened)
- quick settings button in notification bar without effect
- and many issues more....

I now re-installed Cynogenmod by again running the installer. Build number and date are stated at the top of this post.

I suggest that installer version is quite a bit slower in its release cycles, right?

Comment: I suggest that you would comment on an existing answer (in this case: my answer) rather than posting a new answer. And as I said, your current build is written in the entry called "CyanogenMod-Version", not "Build-Number" or "Build Date". Other than that, your could have avoided issues after manually flashing the M4-Build by just doing a full wipe before you flash that M4-build (explanation: http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog/cm-11-m4-post-release-items). And finally, if your problem is solved you should accept an answer in order to close this thread.

Answer (score 2):

I too have a Samsung Galaxy Nexus and I upgraded from CM11 M3 to M4 manually just one week ago.

But I looked it up on my phone and there is an OTA-Update to the M4 build.
Other than that, you can find your current CM11-build under Settings -> About phone and there it says in the entry named CyanogenMod-Version. It should end with your device's code-name (depending on your specific Galaxy Nexus it can be either "toro", "toroplus" or "maguro"; in my case "maguro").

And that update in late february cannot have been the M4-build, because that's just too far in the past. The M4-build was anounced officially by the team of CyanogenMod on march 7th.

I hope I could help you.

PS: If you still do not get the OTA-update, I would recommend you to flash it manually.